# How to make PyCharm mark special code words?

Tags: python, pycharm

My PyCharm does not mark special code words like:

```
class TrainSpliter(object):
    def __init__(self):
```

Anyone knows how can i solve it?

Comment: If you're putting `self` in quotes, it won't be highlighted.

Comment: `self` is not a special code word in Python, it is just a convention.  Some perverted individuals use `this`.  You could call a reference to the current object `Kevin` if you wanted to.

Comment: In which context PyCharm doesn't mark it? Can you provide complete example? Speaking of first argument of a method (`self`) --- PyCharm highlights it regardless of how it is names in code: `self`, `this` or `Kevin`.

Comment: I know, i updated the question. In the given example self is not marked.

Comment: You just need to create proper python files... Right click somewhere in your project directory>New>Python File

Comment: It is a python file. And this is how i created the files. Some words are marked, for example 'if'.

Comment: Depending on which 'special code words' you are referring to, it may well be that, as @cdarke said, 'self' is not a special word. Alternatively, another reason unrelated to python may be that your PyCharm 'theme' is customized in a way that doesn't make it obvious when certain code is recognized as reserver, e.g. your colour for this code is the same or very similar to normal text.